# AWS ec2 ubuntu - run command from calling a web endpoint

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How do you run a particular command using an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance - from a web endpoint?

For example http://ipaddress.com/endpoint triggers the Ubuntu command

For example http://ipaddress.com/endpoint/?parameters=bla triggers the Ubuntu command with some parameters passed in

Comment: AFAIK this isn't built into the AWS platform. You would have to write something custom to do this unless it's built into Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This will not do what you're asking for, but if you want to remotely execute commands that run on an EC2 instance (Amazon Linux or Ubuntu), the Run Command feature of AWS Systems Manager will let you remotely execute commands on an EC2 instance:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html

/Mats